# Passing output of type command as a command line argument in C#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to open a JSON file using the Win32 command `type` and re-direct its output to my C# program through command line arguments.

- `type Demo.json`

gives me

```
{
   "Message" : "Hello World"
}
```

I want to pass it to my C# program via command line arguments as follows

- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Demo.cs`
- `Demo type Demo.json`

But I get output as:
`Demo.json`

Demo.cs includes:

```
using System;
namespace Demo
{
  public class Program
  {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
             Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
      }
  } 
}
```

I want to redirect the output of the `type` command to pass it to the command line argument.

Comment: Have your C# program read from stdin. Use the command line `Demo <"Demo.json"`. Search for C# information about reading from stdin.

Comment: [`demo.exe < type demo.json`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: But how do I fetch them inside the code if I read it from stdin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the contents of a file through the command line arguments. Instead, pipe the data into stdin then have your program read from stdin:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string contents = Console.In.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("Read from stdin: " + contents);
    }
}
```

And to run it:

```
C:\Projects\ConsoleApp1\bin>type my-file.txt | ConsoleApp1.exe
```

Comment: If Console.In.ReadToEnd() reads the entire file contents into memory, that might work well for a 3K .ini file. If the file is 30 GiB it will not work as well. The same thing happens in PowerShell using `$contents = Get-Content 'file.txt'`.